# Azure Traffic Manager routing to Azure Website configured as External Endpoint

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

Here's what I did,

Created an Azure Website (http://myapp1.azurewebsites.net) in Standard tier

Configured Azure Traffic Manager and added endpoint as an Azure endpoint. Trafficmanager routes to the website. Nice!

Removed the endpoint and and added endpoint as an External endpoint. Trafficmanager routes to a 404 page. I provided the FQDN (Fully Qualified domain name) as myapp1.azurewebsites.net.

What is wrong with it? Doesn't Azure allow to have .azurewebsites.net sites to define as endpoint urls?

Endpoint details,
Status - Enabled
Monitor Status - Degraded
Type - External Endpoint

[image: *enter image description here*]

Complete error page details,

```
Error 404 - Web app not found.

The web app you have attempted to reach is not available in this Microsoft Azure App Service region. This could be due to one of several reasons:

1. The web app owner has registered a custom domain to point to the Microsoft Azure App Service, but has not yet configured Azure to recognize it. Click here to read more.

2. The web app owner has moved the web app to a different region, but the DNS cache is still directing to the old IP Address that was used in the previous region. Click here to read more.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External endpoint needs to be outside Azure website.

Comment: No, you can use a website as an external endpoint (although it's not clear why you would want to).  The issue here relates to custom domain name configuration on the web site.

Comment: @Jonathan: I have not configured a custom domain. Was trying to use the Azurewebsite domain.

Answer (score 4):

When using a web site, the web site needs to know what domain name to expect in the 'host' header of the DNS request.  This is the domain name the user types into their browser.

When you add a web site as an endpoint in Traffic Manager, the Traffic Manager domain name (e.g. mysite.trafficmanager.net) is automatically added as a custom domain name in your web site.  And when you remove the web site endpoint, it is removed once again.

However, if you use the external endpoint type, this does not happen.  Because the web site does not recognize the domain name in the host header, a 404 error is returned.

To make this work, you will need to put a vanity domain name in front of Traffic Manager using a CNAME, register the vanity domain name in your web site, and use the vanity domain name from your browser.  (You cannot manually add the Traffic Manager domain name to the web site since you cannot complete the proof-of-ownership validation which web sites demand.)